# Join two tables on two columns, even if table 2 does not have row

Tags: mysql

What I am trying to do is join two tables, lets call them t1 and t2 on two columns. id and name, for this example. t1 will always have id and name, but t2 won't always have id and name. t1 has more columns like viewes, reports, and t2 has other columns that need to be joined. My question is, how can I show 0's for t2's columns if they don't exist?

I hav something similar to this, that joins tables only if both tables' rows have some value.

```
SELECT
 date(t1.start_time) date,
 t1.name,
 t1.viewes,
 t1.reports,
 t2.col5,
 t2.col6
from
 table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2
 on t2.name = t1.name and date(t2.start_time) = date(t1.start_time)
group by
 1,2
order by
 1 desc,
 2 asc
;
```

I have lot's of experience with MySQL, but sometimes find that things need to be hacked to work correctly. What's your suggestion for this problem?

Comment: Your query does what you want. `LEFT OUTER JOIN` means it will return a row even if `table2` doesn't have the matching columns, `INNER JOIN` only returns rows with matches.

Comment: The problem is, it doesn't. It returns rows that are common in both tables.

Comment: @Barmar would adding a where clause after join to filter t2 make a difference here? I think it shouldn't.

Comment: Yes, it would. In all the rows with no match, the t2 values will be `NULL`, and any comparisons with them in the `WHERE` clause (except `IS NULL`) will fail. You should put the filter in the `ON` clause.

Comment: If you had posted the non-working query in the first place, I could have pointed that out earlier.

Comment: @Barmar that worked, I was putting it in where clause, moved it to 'in' and it populated the data I wanted. Thanks for the support man!